# How to monitor Elastic Stack without X-Pack?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-x-pack

Can we monitor the elastic stack 6.0 and above(like elastic search..) without using the X-Pack?As we know many of the Features like security, machine learning, graph APIs don't be supported under BASIC(free Licence). 
So I want to know if there are any APIs, without Licence limitation, can be used to implement those functionalities mentioned above?

Answer (score 2):

All the information should be in the [cluster APIs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster.html), you'll just lack the visualizations.

Monitoring (of the local cluster) is actually included in X-Pack Basic unlike the other features. Any reason you don't want to use it?

Alternatives include [Kopf](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head), [Cerebro](https://github.com/lmenezes/cerebro),... though you'll need to run them as a separate process and watch out for version compatibilities.

Answer (score 1):

We've had success with ElasticHQ for Monitoring (requires python)

https://github.com/ElasticHQ/elasticsearch-HQ

And sentinl for setting up alerts/watchers (it is a plugin for kibana)

https://github.com/sirensolutions/sentinl/wiki

We have set up a reverse proxy to enable ssl/tls and use ubuntu user management to create logins, however, we do not limit access within Kibana itself.

We have little need for graph/machine learning so I am unaware of free alternatives.

The company I work for is heavily Open Source, so these projects suit us.

Comment: Latest versions of Kibana 6.2.x and above has monitoring built in as standard. So you only need to integrate sentnl in order to get alerting (if you even need it).

Comment: Elastalert is also a very good option for non-xpack alerting.